# Past and past perfect in conditionals

Tags: tense, modal-verbs, conditional-constructions, modality

As an EFL learner I know that the first one is second conditional and the next is third conditional. I just want to explain the meaning of the two sentences to my mother, who is learning English, so that she could get the difference just by reading to paraphrased sentences in simple English. Would you mind just paraphrasing the sentences so the difference in meanings would be understandable?

Should I tell her that in second conditional there is a possibility to buy a memory card, but in the third conditional you do not have a chance to buy it even if you have money now?

> 1. If I **had** money, I **would buy** an extra memory card to transfer and save data more easily.
> 2. If I **had had** money, I **would have bought** an extra memory card to transfer and save data more easily.

Answer (score 2):

The primary difference is simply one of tense:

- *If I had money . . . * may have either non-past or past reference:

  > NON-PAST: [I can assure you now that] if I had money **now** (or if I come into money in the near future) I would buy a card **in the present** (or near future).
  >   PAST: [I assured him then that] if I had money **then** (or if I came into money in the near future) I would buy a card **at that time** (or shortly thereafter).
- *If I had had money . . .* has only past reference:

  > [I can assure you now / I assured him then that] if I had had money **then** I would have bought a card **at that time**.

However, these bear quite different semantic implicatures:

- The *irrealis* use of the simple past tense *had* leaves the  possibility open that either you actually **do** have the money now or **did** have the money then, or might at some time subsequent to whichever time you are talking about come into possession of the money.
- The quasi-perfect construction *had had*, which imposes an exclusively past reference on the *irrealis* *had*, cannot bear that open-possibility interpretation. The past eventuality is over-and-done-with, and the *irrealis* use implies that in fact you ***did not*** have the money at that time and therefore ***could not*** buy the card at that time.

Comment: +1 for getting this new information. I didn't know so far that English second conditional can refer to either present or past events, exactly like in my language.

Comment: @LucianSava Apparently it's never taught that way. But there's no such thing in English grammar (as opposed to English pedagogy) as *nth conditionals*. English has, literally, scores of different conditionals; *nth conditionals* are just baby rules for teaching English, and should be discarded as soon as they start contradicting the actual facts on the ground.

Answer (score 0):

Following the guidelines of [Conditional Sentences](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/conditional2.htm), *If I possessed the money at this present time,---* and *If I had possessed the money at the given time in the past,---*. Should you tell her about the possibilities? No, not according to sentence condition. The third condition still leaves the possibility open of buying the card in the future. An example of the chance no longer being possible, if the card was only available for a limited time, now expired, your chance to purchase would be gone. But that would be based upon outside circumstances, not sentence condition.

Comment: The usage of *had had* might be confusing, the first *had* being an auxiliary verb in the past perfect tense, and the last being a verb of possession. In OPs example 2, the past and past to present opportunities to buy are gone, but present or future opportunities would still exist. The memory card might no longer be available for purchase, but that would again be by circumstance, not sentence condition.

Comment: Someone correct me if the first *had* is a linking verb, rather than auxiliary.

Comment: The final *had* in each 'chain' (thus the only *had* in the first example) is not a "linking verb" (*copula* is another technical term). It takes an object, not a "predicate complement", so it's an ordinary *lexical* verb -- more specifically, a transitive verb.

Comment: @StoneyB, Thank you.Transitive verb is the term I had in mind, but couldn't think of it.